# Does mass equal angular momentum?

Tags: classical-mechanics, mass, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, momentum

At the wikipedia pages for angular momentum ($L$) and moment of inertia ($I$) we find the equations:

$$L=I \omega$$

$$I=m r^2$$

where $m$ is mass and $r$ is the distance between said mass and barycenter and $\omega$ is angular velocity.

Now rename the angular velocity as follows: $\omega=\frac{d\theta}{dt}$.

Note that the area of an ellipse sector swept out from a focus is given by:

$$A(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\theta} r^2 \:\: ds$$

And so:

$$\frac{dA}{d\theta}=\frac{r^2}{2}$$

Note that for a mass in an elliptical orbit this area is proportional to time.  Therefore, we can write:

$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}\sim\frac{d\theta}{dA}\sim\frac{1}{r^2}$$

Substituting this back into the first two equations at the top of this post gives:

$$L\sim m$$

Comment: The answer to your question is "No."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the symbol $\sim$ to indicate *proportional to,* not *equal to.* These are different ideas.

If I take Newton's 2nd law $F=ma$ and restrict myself to constant acceleration, then $F\sim m$. I could do the same with constant mass and write $F\sim a$. This doesn't mean force is the same as mass or the same as acceleration. It means, when holding all other variables constant, these two things are proportional.

Another typical way to write this, by the way, is to use the symbol $\propto$.

Comment: You should add that, since the other variables are not constant, the answer to the question is No ...

Comment: @BMS Yes, "proportional to" means "equals up to a constant".  But the constants the equations refer to are a constant of 1/2 and constant relating $dA$ to $dt$ which I think is $4b^2$ ($b$ being semi-minor axis of elliptical orbit).  So these are not the variables in the first two eqs held constant.

Comment: But they have dimensions.